# Use of "it" in the following sentence

Tags: grammaticality

Do I need **it** in the following sentence? I am not that sure about it.

> A coin has two sides. It takes both to flip **it**.

Comment: I don't think you _need_ it, but I think your sentence reads better with it.

Comment: Your sentence #2, " *it takes both to flip it* ", doesn't make sense.

Comment: May you please explain the meaning of "it takes both to flip it"?

Comment: What are you trying to say? That it's not possible to flip a single-sided coin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence won't sound too pleasant without the *it* but it isn't totally necessary to have the word *it* in your sentence.

There are also many other ways that you can structure your sentence, for example:

> A coin has two sides. It takes both **for it to flip.**
>
> A coin has two sides. It takes both **for it to be flipped.**